# neo4j starts and crashes instantly after update to 3.1.3

Tags: neo4j, ubuntu-16.04

today I´ve updated my Neo4j Server (running on Ubuntu) from version 3.1.0 to 3.1.3! Everything works so far, so good.
After restarting my server, it crashes instantly. This happens everytime when I start/restart the server...

---

**This is the part from the error log neo4.log**

```
2017-05-01 15:18:30.896+0000 INFO  Starting...
2017-05-01 15:18:31.950+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on localhost:7687.
2017-05-01 15:18:35.181+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@486c3088' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception. Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@486c3088' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@486c3088' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
        at org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(ServerStartupErrors.java:68)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:227)
        at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:91)
        at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:68)
        at org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint.main(CommunityEntryPoint.java:28)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@486c3088' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:443)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:199)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory, /var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:193)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:124)
        at org.neo4j.server.CommunityNeoServer.lambda$static$0(CommunityNeoServer.java:57)
        at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:89)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:433)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.Procedures@78b283fb' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:443)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:189)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.ProcedureException: Unable to register procedure, because the name `apoc.algo.betweenness` is already in use.
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.ProcedureRegistry.register(ProcedureRegistry.java:81)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.Procedures.register(Procedures.java:103)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.Procedures.register(Procedures.java:76)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.Procedures.start(Procedures.java:209)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:433)
        ... 11 more
nohup: ignoring input
2017-05-01 15:19:58.689+0000 INFO  Starting...
2017-05-01 15:19:59.725+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on localhost:7687.
2017-05-01 15:20:01.504+0000 ERROR Cannot register procedure AssertSchemaProcedure org.neo4j.kernel.api.proc.ProcedureSignature$Builder.mode(Lorg/neo4j/procedure/Mode;)Lorg/neo4j/kernel/api/proc/ProcedureSignature$Builder;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.neo4j.kernel.api.proc.ProcedureSignature$Builder.mode(Lorg/neo4j/procedure/Mode;)Lorg/neo4j/kernel/api/proc/ProcedureSignature$Builder;
        at apoc.schema.AssertSchemaProcedure.signature(AssertSchemaProcedure.java:154)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.ProcedureRegistry.register(ProcedureRegistry.java:53)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.Procedures.register(Procedures.java:103)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.Procedures.register(Procedures.java:76)
        at apoc.ApocKernelExtensionFactory$ApocLifecycle.registerCustomProcedures(ApocKernelExtensionFactory.java:79)
        at apoc.ApocKernelExtensionFactory$ApocLifecycle.start(ApocKernelExtensionFactory.java:67)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:433)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions.start(KernelExtensions.java:86)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:433)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:189)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:124)
        at org.neo4j.server.CommunityNeoServer.lambda$static$0(CommunityNeoServer.java:57)
        at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:89)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:433)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:199)
```

Does anyone had this problem after updating Neo4j or can help me with "understanding" that error log?

Thanks in advance ;)

---

UPDATE

---

When I start Neo4j I´ll get this message:

Starting Neo4j.
Started neo4j (pid 28724). By default, it is available at http://localhost:7474/
*/usr/share/neo4j/bin/neo4j: line 176: /usr/share/neo4j/logs /var/log/neo4j/neo4j.log: No such file or directory*
There may be a short delay until the server is ready.
See /usr/share/neo4j/logs /var/log/neo4j/neo4j.log for current status.

I´ve highlighted the 'suspect' part, which doesn´t appear before updating...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the ultimate cause in your call stack:

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.ProcedureException: Unable to register procedure, because the name `apoc.algo.betweenness` is already in use.
```

This type of exception, where an APOC procedure name is already in use, can be seen when you install a new APOC plugin .jar without removing an existing APOC .jar.

If this applies to you, delete the old APOC .jar and try starting neo4j again.